# Ghoul acquiring abilities

Tags: werewolv.es

So, the h2p states if a ghoul eats a killing role, they get a night kill, and if they eat a WC role, they get a role check.

What if the role falls under both? Like certain Coven roles (Witch, Warlock, Furie, etc). Which ability do they get?

EDIT:
Follow up, what happens  if a ghoul consumes a Revenant Corpse, or the VD zombie?

EDIT2:
Considering items sometimes work in the graveyard, does the Veil of Shadows change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb for determining what takes precedence for situations that have  different possible outcomes is "what benefits the role/team more?".

In the case of the Ghoul, an extra kill is generally more valuable than an extra check, so the kill is awarded if the target is both a witchcraft using role and a killing role.

Targeting an Undead role that is "less powerful" than a Ghoul (Zombie, Corpse, Wight or another Ghoul) awards a stalk.

Items have no affect on the scavenge ability of the Ghoul.